# How can I create a corrupt file with specified file size?

Tags: linux

By *corrupt* I mean make a empty file or take an actual file and corrupting it so it becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=somefile bs=somesize count=1
```

See the man page for details on the size.

Comment: Huh? This just creates a file filled with random bytes, that's not "corrupt" in any way?

Comment: sure, but he didn't mention a type. I thought he wanted read() to fail, i.e. the file should be unreadable at the lowest level. I guess it's just another vague question, then. :)

Answer (score 8):

Burn the file onto a cd/dvd then lightly scratch the disk

Answer (score 8):

Files can contain any arbitrary pattern of bytes, so there is no (digital) way to create a file that is "corrupted". You can certainly modify a file in an existing format (for example, an XML file) so that it no longer is valid in whatever format it's supposed to be, but it's still just a file on disk and is perfectly readable.

You generally need to physically alter the storage medium on which the file is stored, in order to make the file actually *unreadable*.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your best way is to mount a FUSE filesystem which is modified to return errors for specific files. As FUSE really is a filesystem driver (albeit in userspace), it can throw back whatever error code you want.

Comment: I think there is a FUSE implementation that injects random rubbish on client read()'s .. I just can't think of the name off hand. It simulates all kinds of errors.